# How to declare a sort function in Java / Anylogic?

Tags: java, sorting, compare, anylogic

I am a little lost. What's the syntax to declare a sort function in a class ?

I have my class here :

```
public class PLClass 
{
     double PL;
     int index;

/** other functions **/
}
```

And I want to sort a collection of elements PLClass with order based on the element double PL:

```
public ArrayList<PLClass> Mycollec;
Collections.sort(Mycollec, Collections.reverseOrder(PL));
```

I get the following error message :
Description: The method reverseOrder(Comparator) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (double).

Any idea what I am missing ? Thanks !

Comment: Please read up on the Collections interfaces and the Comparator / Comparable interfaces. `Collections.reverseOrder()` either takes no parameter or an instance of Comparator. What is `PL`? You code is incomplete as it stands.

Comment: PL is the attribute I want the element of class PL to be sorted by. It is one of the attribute of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your main intention is to only sort a collection of PLClass based on the element PL then the following might be what you are looking for

```
    Collections.sort(Mycollect,new Comparator<PLClass>(){
        @Override
       public int compare(PLClass o1, PLClass o2) {
          Double i = o1.PL;
          Double j = o2.PL;
          return i.compareTo(j);
       };  
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I meant. Will try right now :-)